# Socket usage with Linux

Tags: python, tcp, socket, debian-wheezy

I am wondering, does anyone know if there is a setting within linux that designates the max amount of time a socket is allowed open? I ask this because for whatever reason, no matter if there is data streaming or not, my sockets close after 7200 seconds on the dot. Its extremely strange, I'm using Python btw.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Linux thing. Check all firewalls and NAT devices in the path between you and the remote server.

Comment: There is no such thing as a max amount of time a socket can be open and also no related tuning.

Comment: Have you checked the other end? Could also possibly be a "protection" on that end, though closing the connection while data is exchanged sounds nonsensical.